# How can i retrieve an unpublished ios app id based on a known app identifier?

Tags: fastlane

Is there a way in fastlane to discover the app id (1234567890) of my unpublished app based on a known app identifier (com.whatever.whatever)?  The app has already been created and is in iTunes connect.  I just need to be able to echo it out programatically it based on the known identifier.

The http://itunes.apple.com/lookup feature does not work if the app isn't in the store yet, so that won't work.

I tried making a lane piecing together some things I found, but it doesn't work:

```
lane :info do
  UI.success("App ID is #{ENV['PRODUCE_APPLE_ID']}")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need it visually, you can run `bundle exec fastlane produce` and you'll get a warning output showing your app id, e.g.:

```
[16:51:18]: [iTC] App 'com.company.appname' already exists (1234567890), nothing to do on iTunes Connect`
```

If you need it programmatically you can use your current approach of inspecting `ENV['PRODUCE_APPLE_ID']`, however note that this environment variable will only be populated after running the `create_app_online` action:

```
lane :info do
    create_app_online
    UI.success("App ID is #{ENV['PRODUCE_APPLE_ID']}")
end
```